# replaceAll and beginning of line (java)

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I would like to use String's `replaceAll` function to delete any char that is not in a given set. I tried

```
x = x.replaceAll("^[A-Za-z]", "");
```

However this is not working because when placed at the beginning of the expression, the ^ character has another meaning (match the beginning of a line).

How can I get the behavior I want? I could not find any help on the correct syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the negation of the range? Then it has to be inside the brackets.

```
x = x.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

More in the [Java Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: I read this page, but it is unclear how to do it when unifying two sets. Thanks anyway for the solution

Answer (score 6):

```
x = x.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

It should be *inside* the brackets.